# heroku launches build and gets stuck

Tags: node.js, heroku

Log:

```
.\yoshi-realese> git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 2449, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2449/2449), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2353/2353), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2449/2449), 4.63 MiB | 2.71 MiB/s, done.
Total 2449 (delta 275), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running build
remote:        > yoshi-v1@1.0.0 build
remote:        > nodemon app.js
remote:        [nodemon] 2.0.19
remote:        [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
remote:        [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
remote:        [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
remote:        [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
remote:        started yoshistore
```

After that nothing happens.

Here is my `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "yoshi-v1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nodemon app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@handlebars/allow-prototype-access": "^1.0.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^6.0.6",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "mongoose": "^6.5.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  }
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQN1J.png)

Comment: What do you expect should happen?

Comment: after the build, compression and launch should occur. when everything is completed, a link to the site will appear in the console

Comment: later in the heroku log there is a line

-----> Timed out running buildpack Node.js

Comment: Please show us your `package.json`. I suspect your build script is trying to actually run your application.

Comment: {
  "name": "yoshi-v1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nodemon app.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@handlebars/allow-prototype-access": "^1.0.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^6.0.6",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "mongoose": "^6.5.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19"
  }
}

Comment: That should be [edit]ed into your question as a code block. As you can see, it is very difficult to read in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your build script tries to run your application:

```
"build": "nodemon app.js"
```

That's not what it is for. The build script is run once per deployment, when Heroku builds your application, to generate whatever artifacts your application needs.

That might involve compiling TypeScript to JavaScript, minifying code, tree shaking, or a whole bunch of other things. I'm not sure what yours should be, but you can try leaving it out entirely.

To *run* your application, Heroku will look at your `Procfile`. If no such file exists, [it will run your start script as a `web` process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specifying-a-start-script). Try changing your `package.json` accordingly:

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "node app.js",
  "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
}
```

Here I have changed `build` to `start`, and also swapped `nodemon` (which is a development tool that should not be used in production) with `node`.